# Free alternative to RocketStream Station?

Tags: ftp, udp, ftp-client

I just tried RocketStream Station (www.rocketstream.com) as an alternative to FTP for transferring large files over long Internet distances (relatively high latency) and was blown away by its performance which for me was over 125 times the speed of FTP. It uses Udp for the data channel or a protocol they call "Pdp".

Are there any free (or cheaper) alternatives to this application?

Answer (score 1):

Kurt,

We use a product from a company called Data Expedition, Inc.  Their ExpeDat software is a high-speed file transfer product that works very well for us (our avg. file size 4GB, 45Mbps lines, between California and Europe).  They are also UDP-based and we compared them to a couple of vendors, roughly 18 months ago, when we were making our decision.  Rocketstream was one of the vendors Data Expedition beat out for our situation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jim. ExpeDat looks very interesting and I will be looking closer at that.

Answer (score 1):

I have to also echo Jim's statement above re: ExpeDat and Data Expedition.  Our particular scenario involves 100 meg connections between NY and the UK with 10's of GBs being moved daily.  For some reason most of the UDP-based applications we tested had a hard time scaling and were only getting us ~50-60% throughput while ExpeDat consistently gets us 90+.

Technology aside, these guys have been really easy to work with (no BS on support or pricing, etc.) and we're pretty glad we found them, definitely a smaller company but one which we've recommended up and down to our clients.  www.dataexpedition.com is there site.  Good luck all!

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is always a good option for sharing files with people. Works very reliably and you get 2 gigs for free.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried Dropbox earlier, but it didn't work for me. I copied a 1.5 GB file to my dropbox in Europe and initially (on the local computer) it gave the impression that it should go very fast, but the file never showed up in my dropbox on the computer in U.S.A. (or in my dropbox web account). I'm not quite sure why that is. It worked with much smaller files and I'm sure I did not exceed the 2 GB free quota.